# Is certainty a vacuous/meaningless concept?

Tags: certainty

What does it mean for one to be certain of something? Many philosophers have tried to make sense of certainty by first modeling belief as a credence value between 0 and 1 and assigning 1 or 0 to certainty.

But this implies that in order to find any meaning in certainty, one must first find meaning in credence. However, if the root of philosophy is to ascertain truth about the world, why is how you subjectively feel about anything relevant at all?

What is the correct credence one should have in the belief that the world is a simulation? 0%? 0.1%? 0.5%? You would be hard pressed to find the answer, even as a range or imprecisely. Worse, the “real” probability of the world being a simulation is obviously either 0 or 1, since the world already exists, and is either a simulation or not. Thus, any credence between 0 or 1 would necessarily be inaccurate with respect to reality anyways.

Because of this trouble, how do we know that credence as a concept is well defined and has any relevance to the reality of the world in the first place?

Many would say that you cannot be certain of the world not being a simulation because you cannot disprove that it is. But why not just say that then?

Instead of saying “you can’t be certain that the world is not a simulation” why not just say “you can’t disprove that the world is not a simulation.” The former seems to involve a concept that doesn’t seem to actually be out there or be relevant in the real world. The latter doesn’t suffer from this flaw.

Comment: If you think the world is a simulation, then your definition of "world" doesn't include the beings doing the simulation. You need a better definition.

Comment: Certainly, I am looking at your question which is not a vacuous/meaningless concept.

Comment: If that which can only be approached asymptotically is vacuous, does that make vacuum vacuous, and hence an infinite recursion of vacuousness?

Comment: *Is certainty a vacuous/meaningless concept?*  Not sure...let me get back to you. Im stuck in a loop: I'm certain that I am uncertain.